# iOS Swift3 - Convert coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, gis, geojson

I'm trying to create annotations on the MapKit from a `geoJSON` file, but the problem is that the coordinates provided by the `geoJSON` file don't match the coordinate system that `MapKit` uses.

**Question** :  How do I convert *read* the geoJSON file and *convert* the coordinates from [``](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/sweref99-13-30/) to `WGS84S`?

Here is an example of what the `geoJSON` file looks like:

```
{"name":"MAPADDRESSPOINT","type":"FeatureCollection"
,"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3008"}}
,"features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{
    "type":"Point","coordinates": [97973.4655999987,6219081.53249992,0]},
        "properties":{
            "ADDRESSAREA_resolved":"Sadelvägen",
            "multi_reader_id":1,
            "multi_reader_full_id":1,
            "BALSTATUS_resolved":"Gällande",
            "REMARKTYPE_resolved":"",
            "FARMADDRESSAREA_resolved":"",
            "geodb_type":"geodb_point",
            "multi_reader_keyword":"GEODATABASE_SDE_2",
            "DEVIATEFROMSTANDARD_resolved":"",
            "geodb_feature_is_simple":"yes",
            "STATUS_resolved":"Ingen information",
            "ADDRESSEDCONSTRUCTIONTYPE_resolved":"",
            "SUPPLIER_resolved":"",
            "multi_reader_type":"GEODATABASE_SDE",
            "geodb_oid":18396,
            "STAIRCASEIDENTIFIER_resolved":"",
            "LOCATIONADDRESSSTATUS_resolved":"Gällande",
            "POSITIONKIND_resolved":"Byggnad",
            "BALADDRESSTYPE_resolved":"Gatuadressplats",
            "COMMENTARY":"","
            DTYPE":"",
            "EXTERNALID":2,"GID":"{DEEA1685-2FF3-4BEB-823D-B9FA51E09F71}",
            "MODIFICATIONDATE":"20170301173751",
            "MODIFICATIONSIGN":"BAL service",
            "OBJECTID":18396,
            "REGDATE":"20110321151134",
            "REGSIGN":"BAL service",
            "STATUS":0,
            "ADDRESSEDCONSTRUCTIONVALUE":"",
            "LABELROTATIONANGLE":0,
            "POSTCODE":"25483",
            "POSITIONKIND":1,
            "REALPROPERTYKEY":"120320803",
            "BALSTATUS":2,
            "BALADDRESSTYPE":1,
            "BALID":"D5650F0B-EE54-4C4C-9C40-A8162118288C",
            "DESIGNATIONVALUE":"",
            "SYNCDATE":"20170301173751",
            "STREETNAME":"Sadelvägen",
            "ADDRESSAREA":554,
            "YARDSNAME":"",
            "PLACENAMEID":"",
            "ADDRESSLABEL":"Sadelvägen 6",
            "DESIGNATIONNUMBERLETTER":"",
            "LOCATIONADDRESSSTATUS":3,
            "CITY":"Helsingborg",
            "ENUMERATOR":"6",
            "SYMBOLROTATIONANGLE":0,
            "POPULARNAME":"",
            "geodb_feature_dataset":"Adress"
        }
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: How did you generate/get this geoJSON? There is no generic specification for what coordinate system to use in a geoJSON and this seems to be something else than geographic coordinates. You should learn what coordinate system this is and then you can convert it to geographic coordinates.

Comment: I have updated the question now

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144538/whats-the-formula-for-converting-sweref99-to-wgs84) question on the Geographic Information Systems StackExchange page, they recommend some tools that you can use for the conversion.

Comment: I have looked into the link, but none of the tools seemed to compatible with Swift

Comment: Unless you can find an algorithm that can be coded in Swift for the conversion, I don't see any better option than using an online tool.

Comment: Is it possible to use an online tool like [this](http://latlong.mellifica.se/)? and use alamofire to use the tool inside function in the app?

Comment: You didn't mention anywhere that your geoJSON is coming from an API. In this case, no, you will need to do the conversion in code. You definitely cannot call an online tool with Alamofire, depending on the implementation of the tool you might be able to use it programatically from a Webview, but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection

Longitude of natural origin 0° 00' 00.000" N
13° 30' 00.000" E

Scale factor at natural origin
1

False easting
150000
meters

False northing
0

FINAL (Playground) version

```
//: [Previous](@previous)

import Foundation

extension Double {
    var rad: Double {
        get {
            return .pi * self / 180.0
        }
    }
    var deg: Double {
        get {
            return 180.0 * self / .pi
        }
    }
}

// SWEREF99 13 30 (GRS80)
let φ0 = 0.0
let λ0 = 13.5.rad
let N0 = 0.0
let E0 = 150000.0
let k0 = 1.0

// GRS80
let a = k0 * 6378137.0
let b = k0 * 6356752.31414034
let n = (a - b)/(a + b)

let n2 = n * n
let n3 = n2 * n
let n4 = n3 * n
let a2 = a * a
let b2 = b * b
let e2 = (a2 - b2)/a2
let H0 = 1.0 + 1.0/4.0*n2 + 1.0/64.0*n4
let H2 = -3.0/2.0*n + 3.0/16.0*n3
let H4 = 15.0/16.0*n2 - 15.0/64.0*n4
let H6 = -35.0/48.0*n3
let H8 = 315.0/512.0*n4

let ν:(Double)->Double = { φ in
    return a/(sqrt(1.0 - e2 * sin(φ) * sin(φ)))
}

let ρ:(Double)->Double = { φ in
    return ν(φ) * (1.0 - e2) / (1.0 - e2 * sin(φ) * sin(φ))
}

let η2:(Double)->Double = { φ in
    return ν(φ) / ρ(φ) - 1.0
}
var arcMeridian1:(Double)->Double = { φ in
    let m = (a + b) / 2 * (H0 * φ + H2 * sin(2.0 * φ) + H4 * sin(4.0 * φ) + H6 * sin(6.0 * φ) + H8 * sin(8.0 * φ))
    return m
}

var arcMeridian:(Double, Double)->Double = { φ1, φ2 in
    return arcMeridian1(φ2) - arcMeridian1(φ1)
}

var cartografic:(Double,Double)->(Double,Double) = { φ, λ in
    let νφ = ν(φ)
    let ρφ = ρ(φ)
    let η2φ = νφ / ρφ - 1.0
    let s1 = sin(φ)
    let s2 = s1 * s1
    let c1 = cos(φ)
    let c2 = c1 * c1
    let c3 = c2 * c1
    let c5 = c3 * c2
    let t2 = s2/c2
    let t4 = t2 * t2

    let k1 = νφ * c1
    let k2 = νφ/2.0 * s1 * c1
    let k3 = νφ/6.0 * c3 * (νφ / ρφ - t2)
    let k4 = νφ/24.0 * s1 * c3 * (5.0 - t2 + 9.0 * η2φ)
    let k5 = νφ/120.0 * c5 * (5.0 - 18.0 * t2 + t4 + 14.0 * η2φ - 58.0 * t2 * η2φ)
    let k6 = νφ/720.0 * s1 * c5 * (61.0 - 58.0 * t2 + t4)

    let Δλ = λ - λ0
    let Δλ2 = Δλ * Δλ
    let Δλ3 = Δλ2 * Δλ
    let Δλ4 = Δλ3 * Δλ
    let Δλ5 = Δλ4 * Δλ
    let Δλ6 = Δλ4 * Δλ

    let N = arcMeridian(φ0,φ) + N0 + Δλ2 * k2 + Δλ4 * k4 + Δλ6 * k6
    let E = E0 + Δλ * k1 + Δλ3 * k3 + Δλ5 * k5

    return (N,E)
}

var geodetic:(Double,Double)->(Double,Double) = { N, E in
    var φ = (N - N0) / a + φ0
    var M = arcMeridian(φ0, φ)

    var diff = 1.0
    repeat {
        φ += (N - N0 - M) / a
        M = arcMeridian(φ0, φ)
        diff = N - N0 - M
    } while abs(diff) > 0.0000000001  // max 3 - 4 iterations
    let E1 = E - E0
    let E2 = E1 * E1
    let E3 = E2 * E1
    let E4 = E3 * E1
    let E5 = E4 * E1
    let E6 = E5 * E1
    let E7 = E6 * E1

    let νφ = ν(φ)
    let νφ3 = νφ * νφ * νφ
    let νφ5 = νφ3 * νφ * νφ
    let νφ7 = νφ5 * νφ * νφ
    let ρφ = ρ(φ)
    let η2φ = νφ / ρφ - 1.0
    let s1 = sin(φ)
    let s2 = s1 * s1
    let c1 = cos(φ)
    let t1 = s1 / c1
    let t2 = t1 * t1
    let t4 = t2 * t2
    let t6 = t4 * t2

    let k1 = 1.0 / (c1 * νφ)
    let k2 = t1 / (2.0 * ρφ * νφ)
    let k3 = 1.0 / (6.0 * νφ3) * (νφ / ρφ + 2.0 * t2)
    let k4 = (t1 / (24.0 * ρφ * νφ3)) * (5.0 + 3.0 * t2 + η2φ - 9.0 * t2 * η2φ)
    let k5 = 1.0 / (120.0 * νφ5) * (5.0 + 28.0 * t2 + 24.0 * t4)
    let k6 = (t1 / (720.0 * ρφ * νφ5)) * (61.0 + 90.0 * t2 + 45.0 * t4)
    let k7 = (t1 / (5040.0 * ρφ * νφ7)) * (61.0 + 662.0 * t2 + 1320.0 * t4 + 720.0 * t6)

    φ = φ - E2 * k2 + E4 * k4 - E6 * k6
    let λ = λ0 + E1 * k1 - E3 * k3 + E5 * k5 - E7 * k7
    return (φ, λ)
}

print("pecision check")
let carto0 = cartografic(55.0.rad, 12.75.rad)
print(carto0,"err:", carto0.0 - 6097487.637, carto0.1 - 102004.871)

let carto1 = cartografic(61.0.rad, 14.25.rad)
print(carto1,"err:", carto1.0 - 6765725.847, carto1.1 - 190579.995)
print()
print("given position: N 6219081.53249992, E 97973.4655999987")
let geo = geodetic(6219081.53249992, 97973.4655999987)
print("geodetic: φ =", geo.0.deg,"λ =", geo.1.deg)

//: [Next](@next)
```

prints

```
pecision check
(6097487.6372101102, 102004.87085248799) err: 0.00021011009812355 -0.000147512007970363
(6765725.8471242301, 190579.99493182387) err: 0.000124230049550533 -6.81761302985251e-05

given position: N 6219081.53249992, E 97973.4655999987
geodetic: φ = 56.0916410844269 λ = 12.6641326192406
```

position on map
[image]

Comment: Impressively good answer!! But is it possible to make it as precise as [this](http://latlong.mellifica.se/) online converter?

Comment: @J.Doe sure, unfortunately the precise example is too big for publish as the answer here.

Comment: @J.Doe sorry, my geo library is not available in open-source version. I suggest you try first check the internet, I am pretty sure there is a lot of information how to calculate it.

Comment: @J.Doe I made an example with more precise calculation, you can use it as is, or you could modify it to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpfull, AND educational. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what are you looking for exactly but what I would do (since you are using swift) is create an extension of MKPointAnnotation and add a new initialiser that takes the geoJSON, parse it, fetch the coordinates (and whatever data you intend to put in the annotation object) and return a MKPointAnnotation with the required data.
just incase you dont know how to parse a JSON here s an example :

```
do {
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geoJSON!,
    options:    JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
let features = dictionary["features"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
let geometry = features[0]["geometry"] as! [String: AnyObject]
....
}catch{
//incase the json doesnt get parsed
}
```

keep going until you reach the coordinates ..;
obviously dont use force cast incase you are hesitate about a value instead use guard or if let ....

Comment: The problem is that the coordinates provided by the geoJSON file doesn't match the available MapKit coordinates

Comment: just parse the JSON and extract the coordinates manually and then create a CLLocationCoordinate2D which you will later assign to the MKPointAnnotation.
just incase you dont know how to parse it, first convert the json to a dictionary for example [String: Anyobject]; then keep doing deep in that dictionary untill you extract the value

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that the coordinates from the geoJSON file looks like this "[97973.4655999987,6219081.53249992,0]", and those coordinates does not exist in the MapKit coordinate system. And I don't know how to detect what system the geoJSON file is using.

Comment: oh damn i didnt even notice that! obviously that s not using the standard long/lat unit, you need to find which unit those are and convert it back