# Convert latitude, longitude between two points to x,y coordinates

Tags: math, gps, geometry, mapping

I'm sorry to ask this question as it's been answered several times. I read over many of them, but I'm still having trouble drawing the connection to my case.

I have two coordinates in latitude and longitude, and I need to map them onto an x-y plane (in meters), with one of them being the origin.

Using a library function, I got the distance between them. I tried using pythagorean theorem to solve the x and y:

d = distance between 2 coordinates

y = 111.320 * (lat2 - lat1)

x = sqrt(d^2 - y^2)

The problem is this is not very accurate, as 111.320 is an average in km and the distance between lat2 and lat1 is in meters (often less than 10) which badly skews the result.

Are there more accurate ways to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have the distance, get the angle with 'atan' function then add cos(angle)*distance to PlaneX and sin(angle)*distance to PlaneY.

Comment: The problem here is that you are not taking into account the intrinsic curvature of the spherical polar coordinate system. What you many want is the *Mercator Projection*: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html

Comment: I found a reference where this problem seems to be described extensively, but maybe you also ran across this one: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for the link. The distances I'm dealing with are often less than 10m. Will the curvature affect the value much?

Comment: @dmr07 if they are *always* that short, then not at all (unless you're at the poles)

Answer (score 1):

If latitude difference is not large, then you can use this approximation for distance along parallel:

```
dx = 111.111 * (lon2 - lon1) * Cos(AverageLatitude)
```

Comment: I've come across this formula. I'm concerned that 111.111 is an approximation in km, with error rates ~0.3. Wouldn't this mean that I could be off by 300m. (my distances are only about 10m apart).

Comment: No, error for meridional arc length is relative, so error in your distances due to this reason should be negligible (millimeters) compared with another reasons (coordinate detection errors)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple implementation of the [transverese mercator projection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666923/3441734) with sub-millimeter precision. just adjust the longitude of origin and false northing and easting against your needs.